# Wicket component auto refresh using JMS listener

Tags: java, spring, jms, wicket, spring-jms

I am trying to create a notification panel using Wicket 7 and Spring boot 1.5.3 as backend.
For notifications I am using JMS and ActiveMQ with Spring boot [JMS with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/).

My question is how can I auto refresh (re-render/update) a wicket component as soon as a message comes in from my JMS Listener.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Use AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior and poll for updates every N seconds
2. Use WebSocketBehavior and push the updates whenever they come. See https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/single.html#_native_websockets

Using WebSockets is recommended but depends whether your application is used by old browsers (IE9 and older).

Comment: Yep. ActiveMQ supports web sockets natively, no need to use JMS to consume-- even if the original publisher is JMS